# What does "She is too intelligent not to understand it" mean?

Tags: meaning

> "She is too intelligent not to understand it".

Is this sentence correct? What does it mean? I think this sentence means "she is so intelligent that she can understand it".

Comment: I parse it as "She is intelligent enough to understand it".

Comment: Why did you roll back a very helpful edit?

Comment: Also please don't post comments saying "Thank you". Instead of posting thank-you comments, you should consider upvoting and accepting good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is essentially correct. The original has a slightly different tone. It suggests that when presented with it (whatever it is) her intelligence will kick in and she will get the idea right away, even if it's a little subtle or unexpected.

Comment: Or that if she says "I didn't understand", she's probably feigning ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding misses it slightly. It means she is so intelligent that it is impossible that she could not understand it. That’s considerably stronger than just “she understands it”.